# Getting Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vehicles::setPassengerSeats()

Tags: php, php-7

I am getting this error:

> uncaught error call to undefine method
>   Vehicles::setPassengerSeats() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\vehicle.php:91.

I also have added screenshot of the error. Kindly check and tell me how can i solve it ? I think i have problem with my sub class but i don't know where?

Here is my source code:

```
<?php  

class Vehicles{
    private $noOfVehicles;
    private $color;
    private $fuel;
    private $speed;

    public function getNoOfVehicles(){
        return $this->noOfMobiles;
    }

    public function setNoOfVehicles($Vehicles){
        $this->noOfMobiles = $Vehicles;
        echo "No of Vehicles are: ".$this->noOfVehicles."</br>";
    }

    public function getColor(){
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function setColor($look){
        $this->color = $look;
        echo "</br>The Color of Vehicle is: ".$this->color."</br>";
    }

    public function getFuel(){
        return $this->fuel;
    }

    public function setFuel($petrol){
        $this->fuel = $petrol;
        echo "</br>The fuel is: ".$this->color."</br>";
    }

    public function getSpeed(){
        return $this->speed;
    }

    public function setSpeed($vehicleSpeed){
        $this->speed = $vehicleSpeed;
        echo "</br>The speed of vehicle is: ".$this->speed."</br>";
    }

}

class PassengerVehicles extends Vehicles{
    private $passengerSeats;

    public function getPassengerSeats(){
        return $this->passengerSeats;
    }

    public function setPassengerSeats($seats){
        return $this->passengerSeats = $seats;
        echo "</br>Passenger Seats are: ".$this->passengerSeats."</br>";
    }

}

class TransportationVehicles extends Vehicles{
    private $noOfDoors;
    private $loadCapacity;

    public function getNoOfDoors(){
        return $this->noOfDoors;
    }

    public function setNoOfDoors($doors){
        return $this->noOfDoors = $doors;
        echo "</br>The No of Doors are: ".$this->noOfDoors."</br>";
    }

    public function getLoadCapacity(){
        return $this->loadCapacity;
    }

    public function setLoadCapacity($capacity){
        return $this->loadCapacity = $capacity;
        echo "The Load Capacity is: ".$this->loadCapacity."</br>";
    }
}

$VehiclesObj = new Vehicles;
$VehiclesObj->setNoOfVehicles("15");
$VehiclesObj->setColor("Black");
$VehiclesObj->setFuel("5 Litre");
$VehiclesObj->setSpeed("120 km/h");

$VehiclesObj->setPassengerSeats("4");
$VehiclesObj->setNoOfDoors("4");
$VehiclesObj->setLoadCapacity("500 KG");

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Ikram, Welcome to StackOverflow!! It would be better if you could paste the error instead of a screenshot. Its easier for other to find a solution for you. Thanks

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vehicles::setPassengerSeats() in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\vehicle.php:91 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\vehicle.php on line 91

Comment: setPassengerSeats are method of the class PassengerVehicles you can't access it from this Obj $VehiclesObj, because it is an instance of class Vehicles and it doesn't have this class.

Comment: in parent class i define the methods and then i call as same in child class i define methods but it's saying that i don't define. kindly check and tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: You have to call `setPassengerSeats()` from a `PassengerVehicles` object. You cannot call the method from a child class (extending a parent class) on the parent if it isn't defined in the parent class. Exactly as @Sfili_81 told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call child methods from a parent. You need to create an instance of the child to be able to call parent methods

```
   class Vehicles{
    private $noOfVehicles;
    private $color;
    private $fuel;
    private $speed;

    public function getNoOfVehicles(){
        return $this->noOfMobiles;
    }

    public function setNoOfVehicles($Vehicles){
        $this->noOfMobiles = $Vehicles;
        echo "No of Vehicles are: ".$this->noOfVehicles."</br>";
    }

    public function getColor(){
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function setColor($look){
        $this->color = $look;
        echo "</br>The Color of Vehicle is: ".$this->color."</br>";
    }

    public function getFuel(){
        return $this->fuel;
    }

    public function setFuel($petrol){
        $this->fuel = $petrol;
        echo "</br>The fuel is: ".$this->color."</br>";
    }

    public function getSpeed(){
        return $this->speed;
    }

    public function setSpeed($vehicleSpeed){
        $this->speed = $vehicleSpeed;
        echo "</br>The speed of vehicle is: ".$this->speed."</br>";
    }

}

class PassengerVehicles extends Vehicles{
    private $passengerSeats;

    public function getPassengerSeats(){
        return $this->passengerSeats;
    }

    public function setPassengerSeats($seats){
        return $this->passengerSeats = $seats;
        echo "</br>Passenger Seats are: ".$this->passengerSeats."</br>";
    }

}

class TransportationVehicles extends Vehicles{
    private $noOfDoors;
    private $loadCapacity;

    public function getNoOfDoors(){
        return $this->noOfDoors;
    }

    public function setNoOfDoors($doors){
        $this->noOfDoors = $doors;
        echo "</br>The No of Doors are: {$this->noOfDoors}</br>";

        return $this->noOfDoors;
    }

    public function getLoadCapacity(){
        return $this->loadCapacity;
    }

    public function setLoadCapacity($capacity){
        return $this->loadCapacity = $capacity;
        echo "The Load Capacity is: ".$this->loadCapacity."</br>";
    }
}

$truck = new TransportationVehicles();
$truck->setNoOfVehicles("15");
$truck->setColor("Black");
$truck->setFuel("5 Litre");
$truck->setSpeed("120 km/h");
$truck->setNoOfDoors("4");
$truck->setLoadCapacity("500 KG");

$taxi = (new PassengerVehicles())->setPassengerSeats('4');
```

In this case, you will have two instances of the Vehicles class + own child.

The first instance is related to the Vehicle itself + transport properties like `$noOfDoors`and `$loadCapacity` - a truck for example. 
The second is an instance of a passenger based vehicle - taxi for example.

And you tried to get passengers option of a taxi from a bus.

Comment: i follow your instructions but i am not getting any output from setNoOfDoors and from setLoadCapacity, Can you please tell why ?
I am getting this output only..
No of Vehicles are: 15

The Color of Vehicle is: Black

The fuel is: 5 Litre

The speed of vehicle is: 120 km/h

Comment: Please check your `setNoOfDoors()` method and see that your echo is under `return`  move `echo` line before return (I've changed code)

Comment: yeah thanks working, another question can you please tell why we are using return in this method ? if we don't return then ?

Comment: @IkramKhizer, yes, you don't need to return any values in the `setSomething($value)` methods. They are just setters, to get values of the properties you should use getters, I see that you are using them well :)

Answer (score 2):

You call method `setPassengerSeats` which is in another class not in `Vehicles` You should create instance first, then to call this method:

```
$passangerVehicle = new PassengerVehicles;
$passangerVehicle->setPassengerSeats("4");
```